# Libre Office garbles text

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, encoding, microsoft-word

Last night I was working on a .doc file that I've been working on for about a week. Before leaving it for the night - I saved it as usual (it was first saved as "Microsoft Word 97/2000/XP/2003", and has been saved using nothing but CTRL+S ever since).

Today when I opened the file, I am greeted with nothing but 5545 pages of garbled text (the original document was about 28 pages long).

This is a sample from the file:

```
#################�###################����########�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###�###����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������###################    ###
```

Any ideas why this happened and how to reverse it? Or how to prevent it happening in the future? I thought it might be an encoding issue (but there were no warnings or anything), but trying to save this in another format does nothing.

Fortunately I also regularly save my documents in pdf in case something like this happens (I've learned to be cautious), but I'd rather not have to copy and paste everything from there back into Libre Office.